# Return object whose destructor has side effects

Tags: c++, c++14

We have a class that helps us send data to telegraf/influxdb (i.e., for monitoring).  It looks roughly like this:

```
class TelegrafSend {
  public:
    // // Constructor does some default stuff based on binary name and context.
    TelegrafSend();
    // Destructor sends the object.
    ~TelegrafSend();
    // Exists in a couple variants.  Probably could have been a template.
    void AddTag(const std::string& tag_name, const std::string& tag_value);
    // Same.
    void AddField(const std::string& field_name, const int field_value);
};
```

To be clear, that looks like this:

```
TelegrafSend TelegrafSend::AddField(const string& field_name, const int field_value) {
    fields_[field_name] = to_string(field_value);
    sent_ = false;
    return *this;
}
```

And this worked great:

```
TelegrafSend telegraf;
telegraf.AddTag("a_tag", "a_value");
telegraf.AddField(kTelegrafCount, 1);
```

and as it goes out of scope, it gets sent, which is nice behaviour, because a function can add a couple metrics as it executes and all exits from the function cause the object to send.

Now I had a clever idea:

```
class TelegrafSend {
  public:
    // // Constructor does some default stuff based on binary name and context.
    TelegrafSend();
    // Destructor sends the object.
    ~TelegrafSend();
    // Exists in a couple variants.  Probably could have been a template.
    TelegrafSend AddTag(const std::string& tag_name, const std::string& tag_value);
    // Same.
    TelegrafSend AddField(const std::string& field_name, const int field_value);
};
```

and so I can write

```
TelegrafSend telegraf.AddTag("a_tag", "a_value").AddField(kTelegrafCount, 1);
```

The problem here is that I'm creating temporaries and so, while this works in the end, each return creates a temporary that gets destroyed and so sent on to telegraf.  This is really inefficient for influxdb without even talking about bad practice in C++.

I've tried a couple variations on return rvalue references, but either I try to return a reference to a temporary or stack variable or I do something equally daft.  The examples I've found in production do so much else that I'm not sure precisely what to do.

Any pointers to best practice for this pattern?  Or am I trying to do something syntactical that I just shouldn't do?

Comment: Why do you return a new object and not `*this` as is the usual practice?

Comment: Just return a reference. Or you can write a copy constructor.

Comment: Or a move constructor.

Comment: I'm confused. `TelegrafSend a = telegraf.AddTag("a_tag", "a_value").AddField(kTelegrafCount, 1);` would you want `a` to be a copy of what's returned by `AddTag`, a reference to it, or a moved version of the return'd object? NOTE: `AddTag` & `AddField` should almost certainly return either `T&` or even `const T&`.

Comment: I do return `*this`, I've edited the question.  But I'm also seeing the destructor getting called for each stage of the expression.

Comment: Returning a reference to self is a common pattern (see "method chaining" and "fluent interface"), so it will sually be recognized together with the very few pitfalls. It's also what a good `operator=` does.

Comment: Yup, @Jarod42 noted the same thing, below.  Trying not to leak references to temporaries, I quite forgot that I was in class context.  Thanks, all, for seeing through my myopia!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must return reference to self in those methods instead of creating new object.
Implementing move constructor is also a possibility to consider.

```
class TelegrafSend {
  public:
    TelegrafSend();
    ~TelegrafSend();
    TelegrafSend(const TelegrafSend&) = delete;
    TelegrafSend& operator = (const TelegrafSend&) = delete;
    TelegrafSend(TelegrafSend&&); // possibly = delete;
    TelegrafSend& operator = (TelegrafSend&&); // possibly = delete;

    // Exists in a couple variants.  Probably could have been a template.
    TelegrafSend& AddTag(const std::string& tag_name, const std::string& tag_value)
    {
        /*..*/
        return *this;
    }
    // Same.
    TelegrafSend& AddField(const std::string& field_name, const int field_value)
    {
        /*..*/
        return *this;
    }

};
```

And then you can use:

```
TelegrafSend{}.AddTag("a_tag", "a_value").AddField(kTelegrafCount, 1);
```

Comment: wouldn't it be nicer to have value semantics and have the implementation base on an optional<impl> to track "activeness"?

Comment: @RichardHodges Don't value semantics conflict with the "on scope exit" stuff? Would you use an internal reference count or something to make sure only the "last" one gets sent?

Comment: @RichardHodges: Not sure what you mean. but if OP wants move semantic, a flag `bool` or `optional` would probably be required to do noop in destructor for moved object.

Comment: I've edited the original question to note that I do return `*this`.  But I also see the destructor being called for each stage of that chain.

Comment: Oh, I see, you're returning reference, and it's *this, so it's persistent.  Right, just a sec...

Comment: Yup, that's it, I'm a dufus.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would implement in terms of `std::optional` and provide a move constructor, in order to provide an automatic "validity" indicator during the destructor.

Note that moving from an optional does not empty it, it only moves the contents out, so you must reset the optional.

Complete example:

```
#include <optional>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct TelegrafSend 
{
    // // Constructor does some default stuff based on binary name and context.
    TelegrafSend();

    TelegrafSend(TelegrafSend&& other);
    TelegrafSend(TelegrafSend const& ) = delete;
    TelegrafSend& operator=(TelegrafSend const& ) = delete;
    TelegrafSend& operator=(TelegrafSend && ) = delete;

    // Destructor sends the object.
    ~TelegrafSend();

    TelegrafSend& AddTag(const std::string& tag_name, const std::string& tag_value);
    TelegrafSend& AddField(const std::string& field_name, const int field_value);

private:

    struct Impl
    {
        std::string narrative;

        void more(std::string const& s)
        {
            if (!narrative.empty())
                narrative += '\n';
            narrative += s;
        }

        void emit()
        {
            if (narrative.empty())
                std::cout << "{empty}\n";
            else
                std::cout << narrative << '\n';
        }
    };

    std::optional<Impl> impl_;

};

TelegrafSend::TelegrafSend() 
: impl_(Impl())
{

}

TelegrafSend::TelegrafSend(TelegrafSend&& other)
: impl_(std::move(other.impl_))
{
    other.impl_.reset();
}

TelegrafSend::~TelegrafSend() 
{
    if(impl_.has_value())
        impl_->emit();
}

TelegrafSend& TelegrafSend::AddTag(const std::string& tag_name, const std::string& tag_value)
{
    auto s = "Tag : " + tag_name + " : " + tag_value;
    impl_->more(s);
    return *this;
}

TelegrafSend& TelegrafSend::AddField(const std::string& field_name, const int field_value)
{
    auto s = "Field : " + field_name + " : " + std::to_string(field_value);
    impl_->more(s);
    return *this;
}


auto test(TelegrafSend ts = {}) -> TelegrafSend
{
    ts.AddTag("foo", "bar").AddField("baz", 6);
    return ts;
}

int main()
{
    {
        test(), std::cout << "hello\n";
    }

    std::cout << "world\n";
}
```

expected output:

```
hello
Tag : foo : bar
Field : baz : 6
world
```

https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/755d3d161b9d48b3

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about `std::optional`.  It's another good reason for me to push for us to upgrade from C++14 to C++17.  That said, @Jarod42 pretty much hit it on the head that I needed to return `*this` as a reference and not by value.

Comment: @jma boost has optional also. The other benefit of c++17 is guaranteed return value optimisation. There is no good reason to stay on c++14.